# Limit Check boxes to 2 and uncheck all check boxes when last checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Want to limit the checkbox selection to 2 and when someone selects none of the above, all others should be unchecked!   Can we do this using the formElement here? or any other way to do this? ..................................................................................................................................................................

```
<div class="layout-col col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div id="formElement13"  form-element-layout row">
            <div style="text-align:left;" class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <label  for="fe2807">What area are you most experienced in? (max choose 2)
                        </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="field-control-wrapper LV_valid_field" id="fe2807">
                            <div class="list-order one-column"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-Inbound1"
                                    value="Inbound sales" name="checkboxes2"><label class="checkbox-aligned-item-label"
                                    for="checkbox-Inbound1">Inbound sales</label><br></div>
                            <div class="list-order one-column"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-Outbound1"
                                    value="Outbound sales" name="checkboxes2"><label class="checkbox-aligned-item-label"
                                    for="checkbox-Outbound1">Outbound sales</label><br></div>
                            <div class="list-order one-column"><input type="checkbox"
                                    id="checkbox-Account1" value="Account management"
                                    name="checkboxes2"><label class="checkbox-aligned-item-label"
                                    for="checkbox-Account1">Account management</label><br></div>
                            <div class="list-order one-column"><input type="checkbox"
                                    id="checkbox-Sales support/customer1"
                                    value="Sales support/customer success" name="checkboxes2"><label
                                    class="checkbox-aligned-item-label"
                                    for="checkbox-Sales support/customer1">Sales support/customer
                                    success</label><br></div>
                            <div class="list-order one-column"><input type="checkbox"
                                    id="checkbox-Business1" value="Business development"
                                    name="checkboxes2"><label class="checkbox-aligned-item-label"
                                    for="checkbox-Business1">Business development</label><br></div>
                            <div class="list-order one-column"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-Sales1"
                                    value="Sales manager" name="checkboxes2"><label class="checkbox-aligned-item-label"
                                    for="checkbox-Sales1">Sales manager</label><br></div>
                            <div class="list-order one-column"><input type="checkbox"
                                    id="checkbox-Sales12" value="Sales operations"
                                    name="checkboxes2"><label class="checkbox-aligned-item-label"
                                    for="checkbox-Sales12">Sales operations</label><br></div>
                            <div class="list-order one-column"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-Sales123"
                                    value="Sales marketing" name="checkboxes2"><label
                                    class="checkbox-aligned-item-label" for="checkbox-Sales123">Sales
                                    marketing</label><br></div>
                            <div class="list-order one-column"><input type="checkbox"
                                    id="checkbox-Sales1234"
                                    value="Sales training, learning, and development" name="checkboxes2"><label
                                    class="checkbox-aligned-item-label"
                                    for="checkbox-Sales1234">Sales training,
                                    learning, and development</label><br></div>
                            <div class="list-order one-column"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-Partner1"
                                    value="Partner Sales" name="checkboxes2"><label class="checkbox-aligned-item-label"
                                    for="checkbox-Partner1">Partner Sales</label><br></div>
                            <div class="list-order one-column"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-LeadG1"
                                    value="Lead Generation" name="checkboxes2"><label
                                    class="checkbox-aligned-item-label" for="checkbox-LeadG1">Lead
                                    Generation</label><br></div>
                            <div class="list-order one-column"><input type="checkbox"
                                    id="checkbox-None" value="None of the above"
                                    name="checkboxes2"><label class="checkbox-aligned-item-label"
                                    for="checkbox-None">None of the above</label><br></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you add what you have tried so far?

Comment: Can you explain this _"and when someone selects none of the above, all others should be unchecked!"_

Comment: @ruleboy21, I have 12 checkboxes, I want to limit checkboxes to 2 when some select in the first 11. When the last check box is checked, I want all other checkboxes to be unchecked

Comment: 1.Inbound sales
2.Outbound sales
3.Account management
4.Sales support/customer success
5.Business development
6.Sales manager
7.Sales operations
8.Sales marketing
9.Sales training, learning, and development
10.Partner Sales
11.Lead Generation
12.None of the above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly try this code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.field-control-wrapper input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
        var $checkboxes = $(this).closest('.field-control-wrapper').find('input[type="checkbox"]');
        if( $(this).val() === 'None of the above' ){
            // uncheck all if 'None of the above is selected'
            $checkboxes.not(this).prop('checked', false);
        }else if( $checkboxes.filter(':checked').length >= 3 ){
            // uncheck all checked if more than two checkboxes are selected
            $checkboxes.not(this).prop('checked', false);
        }else{
            // uncheck 'None of the above' if any other checkbox is selected
            $(this).closest('.field-control-wrapper')
                   .find('input[type="checkbox"][value="None of the above"]')
                   .prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="layout-col col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div id="formElement13" class="form-element-layout row">
        <div style="text-align:left;" class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <label  for="fe2807">What area are you most experienced in? (max choose 2)
                    </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="field-control-wrapper LV_valid_field" id="fe2807">
                        <div class="list-order one-column"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-Inbound1"
                                value="Inbound sales" name="checkboxes2"><label class="checkbox-aligned-item-label"
                                for="checkbox-Inbound1">Inbound sales</label><br></div>
                        <div class="list-order one-column"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-Outbound1"
                                value="Outbound sales" name="checkboxes2"><label class="checkbox-aligned-item-label"
                                for="checkbox-Outbound1">Outbound sales</label><br></div>
                        <div class="list-order one-column"><input type="checkbox"
                                id="checkbox-Account1" value="Account management"
                                name="checkboxes2"><label class="checkbox-aligned-item-label"
                                for="checkbox-Account1">Account management</label><br></div>
                        <div class="list-order one-column"><input type="checkbox"
                                id="checkbox-Sales support/customer1"
                                value="Sales support/customer success" name="checkboxes2"><label
                                class="checkbox-aligned-item-label"
                                for="checkbox-Sales support/customer1">Sales support/customer
                                success</label><br></div>
                        <div class="list-order one-column"><input type="checkbox"
                                id="checkbox-Business1" value="Business development"
                                name="checkboxes2"><label class="checkbox-aligned-item-label"
                                for="checkbox-Business1">Business development</label><br></div>
                        <div class="list-order one-column"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-Sales1"
                                value="Sales manager" name="checkboxes2"><label class="checkbox-aligned-item-label"
                                for="checkbox-Sales1">Sales manager</label><br></div>
                        <div class="list-order one-column"><input type="checkbox"
                                id="checkbox-Sales12" value="Sales operations"
                                name="checkboxes2"><label class="checkbox-aligned-item-label"
                                for="checkbox-Sales12">Sales operations</label><br></div>
                        <div class="list-order one-column"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-Sales123"
                                value="Sales marketing" name="checkboxes2"><label
                                class="checkbox-aligned-item-label" for="checkbox-Sales123">Sales
                                marketing</label><br></div>
                        <div class="list-order one-column"><input type="checkbox"
                                id="checkbox-Sales1234"
                                value="Sales training, learning, and development" name="checkboxes2"><label
                                class="checkbox-aligned-item-label"
                                for="checkbox-Sales1234">Sales training,
                                learning, and development</label><br></div>
                        <div class="list-order one-column"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-Partner1"
                                value="Partner Sales" name="checkboxes2"><label class="checkbox-aligned-item-label"
                                for="checkbox-Partner1">Partner Sales</label><br></div>
                        <div class="list-order one-column"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-LeadG1"
                                value="Lead Generation" name="checkboxes2"><label
                                class="checkbox-aligned-item-label" for="checkbox-LeadG1">Lead
                                Generation</label><br></div>
                        <div class="list-order one-column"><input type="checkbox"
                                id="checkbox-None" value="None of the above"
                                name="checkboxes2"><label class="checkbox-aligned-item-label"
                                for="checkbox-None">None of the above</label><br></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!! when "none of the above"(last option) is checked, all other 11 have to be automatically unchecked.

Comment: @sk_nath I've updated my JavaScript. Please try again and let me know if it works.

Comment: perfect!! Thanks, man!